# Sketch the complex function: $z\overline{z}+(1+2i)z+(1-2i)+1=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

Tried sketching the complex function: $z\overline{z}+(1+2i)z+(1-2i)+1=0$

I first simplified it by converting $z=x+yi$

I got: $(x+yi)(x-yi)+(1+2i)(x+yi)+(1-2i)+1=0$

Which gave me this implicit function: $$(x^2+y^2+x-2y+2)+(2x+y-2)i=0$$

This is where I got confused as I don't know how to go further and sketch this function.

Could it be that there's a typo in the question or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 my question is: can anyone help by guiding me on how to sketch that function?

Comment: If your calculation is correct (I have not checked) then the real part and the imaginary part are both $0$. But the real part cannot be $0$ (complete the squares).  I suspect there is a typo and you want $(1-2i)\bar{z}$.

Comment: If indeed there is a $\bar{z}$ missing as I suspect, we get a circle. It is a nice complex number exercise to get this without going to $x+iy$.

Comment: You are a genius Nicolas. I agree with your suggestion 100%. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.  I am a typo veteran.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that is not a function.

Comment: The function you are interested in might be $$z\overline{z}+(1+2i)z+(1-2i)\overline{z}+1,$$ which happens to be equal to $$|z+1-2i|^2-4,$$ hence the set of $z$ such that this is zero is the circle centered at $-1+2i=(-1,2)$ with radius $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $(x^2 +y^2 +x−2y+2)+(2x+y−2)i=0 $ so this complex number is identically zero, meaning that both real and imaginary parts must be zero.

However, looking at the real part, you have$$x^2 +y^2 +x−2y+2=0$$ $$\Rightarrow(x+\frac 12)^2+(y-1)^2=-2+1+\frac 14<0,$$ so there are no real $x$ and $y$ satisfying this equation and hence no locus.

Answer (score 1):

Already you have obtained that $$Z=(x^2+y^2+x-2y+2)+(2x+y-2)i=0$$
Note that $$x^2+y^2+x-2y+2=(x+\frac12)^2+(y-1)^2+\frac34\gt0.$$ Hence $\Re( Z)\gt 0$ and $Z\not=0.$
Therefore, there are no such complex numbers.